# Create json from python dict

Tags: python, json

I try to create a peace of JSON from a python dict. Unfortunately I am not able to get the correct format yet. I need a array in my json object 'types'. How can I fix this?

My code:

```
import json
association_item = {}
association_item['types']={}
association_item['types']['associationCategory'] = 'A'
association_item['types']['associationTypeId'] = '4'
```

My dict:

```
{'types': {'associationCategory': 'A', 'associationTypeId': '4'}}
```

My JSON:

```
{
    "types": {
        "associationCategory": "A",
        "associationTypeId": "4"
    }
}
```

What i want:

```
{
    "types": [{
        "associationCategory": "A",
        "associationTypeId": "4"
    }]
}
```

Comment: I don't see why you'd expect a dictionary value to be output as an _array_ of an object. If that's what you want, you need to change the outer dictionary to include a _list_ of dictionaries not just a dictionary. You can basically just write the same thing in Python as the JSON you want to output, because Python can use single _or_ double quotes on strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it correctly, like

```
association_item['types'] = 
    [ { 'associationCategory': 'A',
        'associationTypeId': '4' } ]
```